# Best way to store users to allow single sign-on for multiple asp.net mvc websites

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database-design, architecture, single-sign-on

I have multiple asp.net mvc websites hosted in sub folders of a main domain. Each website has its own sql server database. Currently users need to sign up to each individual website if they want access but I am looking for a sso solution. I guess a little bit like how ebay works where you can sign up in one country's domain but can log into ebay from any other of the domains ebay has sites for.

I am looking for the best architectural design to achieve this. After a lot of googling this seems to be the only solution that fits the bill but wanted to check first (http://arunendapally.com/post/implementation-of-single-sign-on-(sso)-in-asp.net-mvc). If this is the right approach how does that effect the database design, would the users now only get stored in their own database all of the other websites have access to?

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe moving the authentication part of your application somewhere else would be a better option.

You could try the approach suggested in your link.
Another option would be to look at external providers.
I'm thinking here about azure active directory (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-whatis/ with this example http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/developing-aspnet-apps-with-windows-azure-active-directory) or auth0 (https://auth0.com/) for example.

That way you have a separate place for your user accounts which are in a database on the cloud which you don't have to manage. Somthing like azure active directory allows you to also set which users are allowed to access which app, which is also something you need to take into account.